# Searching through exploded string based on variable combined with string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In my database I have a string called "Cart".

```
$cart = "1+10,2+10,3+10,5+10,6+10"
$openCart = explode(",", $cart);
```

Inside $openCart I want to search for the number and plus signs before adding new information to this array.
I have tried **array_search** and **in_array** but neither let me search for a value like "3+".
array_search only allowed me to search for complete strings, such as "3+10" while in_array didnt like it when I ended my search string on the plus sign.

*Further context:*
In the end, the ideal code for this function would be somewhere along the following:

```
$pID = 3;
$pOrder = 4;
$openCart = explode(',', $cart);

//Search where $pID . "+" matches a value inside $openCart
$specProd = explode ('+' $openCart[/*Location that got matched*/]);
$specProd[1] = $specProd[1] + $pOrder;

$impProd = implode ('+', $specProd);
$specProd[] = impProd;
$newCart = implode (',', $specProd[]);

//upload the string of $newCart back to the database.
```

Currently I am just stuck on searching through the array and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you should used `preg_grep` function instead of array_search and also this example will help you https://coderwall.com/p/u0foua/like-array_search-but-searches-a-full-string

Comment: or use `array_map` and call a function on each item of your exploded string

Comment: Why do you need to explode the string in the first place? Just use strpos or preg_match and search the string instead. I'm quite sure it's quicker than looping each element of an srray

Comment: Each combination stands for a product and amount of orders. I just store it all as a string which I explode when I need access to specifics. This method was advised to me in the early construction of the site and now its too late to go back, haha! 
In order to avoid specific ID's to appear multiple times in the string, I want to loop through the $openCart to add or deduct the $pOrder from the second part of the string, before collapsing everything back into one string again.

Comment: So `6` is the product and `+10` is the amount? In that case I can give you a much better solution

Comment: @Andreas exactly. I dont want duplicate products (6), but I do want the amount (10) as a separate number I can edit. Hence me looking for (6+) because I know this will be a constant, while (10) could be any number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe handling it as a string is the most efficient way to do it.
If you first explode then you need to loop or regex each item of the array.

This method uses preg_replace_callback which finds patterns and returns the string according to what you want done with it.

In this case we need to find the product and add the change to the number after the + sign.

```
$cart = "1+10,2+10,3+10,5+10,6+10";

$product = 3;
$change = 5;

$finalcart = preg_replace_callback("/(.*" .$product . "\+)(\d+)(.*)/", function($m) use($change){
    return $m[1] . ($m[2]+$change) . $m[3];
}, $cart);
echo $finalcart;
// 1+10,2+10,3+15,5+10,6+10
//           ____
```

https://3v4l.org/XHDXH

The regex pattern:

```
"/          // start of pattern
(.*"        // capture anything 
.$product . // including the product
"\+)        // and a litteral + to $m[1]
(\d+)       // capture a number to $m[2] (the amount)
(.*)        // and capture again anything, to $m[3]
/"          // end of pattern
```

This is then used in the callback function to change the `$m[2]` with `+$change` and then returned back to `$finalcart`

Comment: I see, I have to look into these regex patterns because they look quite extensive. If I would turn $change into -5, it would still subtract it from $product, correct?

Comment: @DanieldeRidder Yes. https://3v4l.org/Ada2M but, it will not work if you get a negative value (15-20). That will output `3+-5`

Comment: That is great to hear, I will try and implement this into my coding then! That should cut down the number of lines significantly haha.
Thank you very much Andreas.

Comment: One thing to remember is that if the product is not in the string nothing will happen. This code will only add to an existing product. But if nothing is changed it's easy to handle with a `if cart == finalcart` as you can see here: https://3v4l.org/BAYFY

Comment: Ah yes, I already made a workaround to see if the value was in the array in the first place. But thank you very much for thinking with me :)

Answer (score 0):

It finds an element's key

```
<?php
$cart = "1+10,2+10,3+10,5+10,6+10";
$openCart = explode(",", $cart);
$needle = "3+";
$return = array_keys(array_filter($openCart, function($var) use ($needle){
    return strpos($var, $needle) !== false;
}));
if(!empty($return)){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: This would have been a lot easier, yes..
But how can I edit this code to give me the specific location where the needle was found?
Because I`ll need that in order to edit the array

Comment: just print or var_dump `$return`, It will have element keys

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have something functional tinkered together, but judging from the comments just before I am posting this, there should be an easier way.

In any case, here is what I came up with by myself.

```
$Cart = '1+10,2+10,3+10,5+10,6+10';
$pID = 3;
$pString = $pID . "+";
$pOrder = 5;
$pLoc;

echo $Cart;
echo "<br/>";
$openCart = explode (",", $Cart);

$cartLenght = count($openCart);
for ($i = 0; $i<$cartLenght; $i++){
    $pos = stripos($openCart[$i], $pString);
    if ($pos !== false){
        $pLoc = $i;
    }
}
$specProd = explode ('+', $openCart[$pLoc]);
$specProd[1] = $specProd[1] + $pOrder;
$impProd = implode('+', $specProd);
$openCart[$pLoc] = $impProd;
$finalCart = implode(",", $openCart);
echo $finalCart;
```

The results:
Cart: 1+10,2+10,3+10,5+10,6+10
finalCart: 1+10,2+10,3+15,5+10,6+10